# Checking to see if a database duplicate with Null field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to check and see if there is a duplicate entry in the database before adding an entry. Here are my current models --

```
class Education(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, choices=YEAR)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    employments = models.ManyToManyField(Employment)
```

On the form, a user must enter a school. Class year and degree are optional. To check for duplicate entries, right now I have --

```
if form.is_valid() and request.POST['school']:
    school = form.cleaned_data['school']
    try:
        school_object = Education.objects.get(school=form.cleaned_data['school'],
                                              class_year=form.cleaned_data['class_year'],
                                              degree = form.cleaned_data['degree'])
    except (Education.DoesNotExist):
        school_object = Education(school=form.cleaned_data['school'],
                                  class_year=form.cleaned_data['class_year'],
                                  degree = form.cleaned_data['degree'])
        school_object.save()
        profile.educations.add(school_object)
        profile.save()
```

I am getting an ValueError if the class_date is not filled out. How to fix this and also when checking for duplicates? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, unless you've got a great reason you really shouldn't be accessing post variables without sending them through a form.

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.form):
  school = forms.CharField()
  degree = forms.CharField(required=False)
  class_year = forms.CharField(required=False)

  def clean(self):
    if not self.cleaned_data.has_key('degree'):
      self.cleaned_data['degree'] = None
    if not self.cleaned_data.has_key('class_year'):
      self.cleaned_data['class_year'] = None
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Then when you're processing the view:

```
...
if request.method == "POST":
  form = MyForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    try:
      # NOTE that the objects.get method will raise MultipleObjectsReturned if the
      # database has more than one object that matches the query
      my_object = Education.objects.get(school=form.cleaned_data['school'], 
        class_year=form.cleaned_data['class_year'], 
        degree = form.cleaned_data['degree'])
    except Education.DoesNotExist:
      my_object = Education(school=form.cleaned_data['school'], 
        class_year=form.cleaned_data['class_year'], 
        degree = form.cleaned_data['degree'])
else:
  form = MyForm()
...
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem of having a Null/None field for the class_year. It will still create a ValueError for invalid literal with base 10(). Any other ideas?

Comment: I changed the clean method to as follows, which now works:     
`if not self.cleaned_data.get('class_year'):`
    `self.cleaned_data['class_year'] = None`
`if not self.cleaned_data.get('degree'):`
    `self.cleaned_data['degree'] = ''`
`return self.cleaned_data`

Answer (score 1):

In views:

```
if 'Add School' in request.POST.values():
    form = EducationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and request.POST['school']:
        school = form.cleaned_data['school']
        try:
            school_object = Education.objects.get(school=form.cleaned_data['school'],
                                              class_year=form.cleaned_data['class_year'],
                                              degree = form.cleaned_data['degree'])
        except (Education.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            school_object = Education(school=form.cleaned_data['school'],
                                              class_year=form.cleaned_data['class_year'],
                                              degree = form.cleaned_data['degree'])
            school_object.save()
            profile.educations.add(school_object)
            profile.save()
            return redirect('edit_education')
```

Or, using `get_or_create` to simplify:

```
if 'Add School' in request.POST.values():
    form = EducationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and request.POST['school']:
        school = form.cleaned_data['school']
        school_object, created = Education.objects.get_or_create(school=form.cleaned_data['school'],
                                          class_year=form.cleaned_data['class_year'],
                                          degree = form.cleaned_data['degree'])
        if created:
            profile.educations.add(school_object)
            profile.save()
            return redirect('edit_education')
```

In forms:

```
YEAR = ([(x, x) for x in range(1970,2015)])
YEAR.append((0,'Select Year'))
YEAR.reverse()

class EducationForm(forms.Form):
    school = forms.CharField()
    class_year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR, required=False)
    degree = forms.CharField(required=False)
    def clean(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data.get('class_year'):
            self.cleaned_data['class_year'] = None
        if not self.cleaned_data.get('degree'):
            self.cleaned_data['degree'] = ''
        return self.cleaned_data
```